# How to speed up an OctoberCMS/Laravel 5.1 Application?

Tags: php, performance, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using OctoberCMS (CMS built on Laravel 5.1). But the issue is that the website is very slow.

I minified HTML,CSS,JS files and even minified octobercms's libraries itself and still have the same problem.

I tried to cache static files by editing `.htaccess` file it came a little faster but still so slow when I tested it using `google speed test`

When I did install wordpress on my server and tested it it was much faster than my OctoberCMS site.

Does Anyone knows why is that? and how to fix this speed issue?

Comment: Too broad in  my opinion.  There are far too many things to check to cover in one answer.   If this is a commercial site, hire an expert, otherwise start researching on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to follow some tutorials online and reached to a good solution.

I added this to my `.htaccess` file.

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.com[NC]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# HTML
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 days"

# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>


<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                  "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/ld+json" \
                                  "application/manifest+json" \
                                  "application/rdf+xml" \
                                  "application/rss+xml" \
                                  "application/schema+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                  "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                  "application/x-javascript" \
                                  "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                  "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "font/eot" \
                                  "font/opentype" \
                                  "image/bmp" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                  "image/x-icon" \
                                  "text/cache-manifest" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/javascript" \
                                  "text/plain" \
                                  "text/vcard" \
                                  "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                  "text/vtt" \
                                  "text/x-component" \
                                  "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                  "text/xml"

</IfModule>
```

And the website has been a lot faster.